# Docker не разворачивает ARG в dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Есть часть dockerfile:

```
ARG DEFAULT_OS=debian
ARG DEFAULT_VERSION=latest
ARG CMAKE_SOURCE_URL=http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.9/cmake-3.9.4.tar.gz
ARG BOOST_SOURCE_URL=https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.65.1/source/boost_1_65_1.tar.bz2
FROM ${DEFAULT_OS}:${DEFAULT_VERSION}
RUN ["apt-get", "update"]           # 
RUN ["apt-get", "upgrade", "-y"]    # 
RUN ["apt-get", "install",  \
    "libcurl4-gnutls-dev",  \
    "build-essential",      \
    "ca-certificates",      \
    "libssl-dev",           \
    "wget",                 \
    "curl",                 \
    "-y"                    \
]
WORKDIR /root
RUN wget ${CMAKE_SOURCE_URL} ## Не разворачивается
RUN wget ${BOOST_SOURCE_URL} ##
```

В выше приведенном контексте не разворачиваются переменные `CMAKE_SOURCE_URL` и `BOOST_SOURCE_URL` ни в каком из вариантов(`$VAR, "$VAR", "${VAR}", ${VAR}`) в обоих видах команды RUN (RUN shell И RUN exec). Пробовал дефолтные значения сразу писать в двойных кавычках.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это же прямым текстом в документации написано

> An ARG declared before a FROM is outside of a build stage, so it can’t be used in any instruction after a FROM. To use the default value of an ARG declared before the first FROM use an ARG instruction without a value inside of a build stage

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: Да, я уже до этого дошел. Но как-то не логично получается.